# The index page does not open at the top of the page, it opens directly on the page form

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, html, xcode

I have a problem, I created an index with a multi-step contact form. The only problem is that when I load the page from mobile it opens directly on the contact form and does not normally open at the top. thank you all.

I hope I have correctly attached the code. If you need some other file or different code, let me know, thank you very much!

```js
/*jQuery.validator.setDefaults({
    debug: false,
    success: "valid"
});

$("#myform").validate({

    rules: {
        field: {
            required: true,
        }
    }
});*/

$(document).ready(function() {

    var navListItems = $('div.setup-panel div a'),
        allWells = $('.setup-content'),
        allNextBtn = $('.nextBtn');

    allWells.hide();

    navListItems.click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var $target = $($(this).attr('href')),
            $item = $(this);

        if (!$item.hasClass('disabled')) {
            navListItems.removeClass('btn-primary').addClass('btn-default');
            $item.addClass('btn-primary');
            allWells.hide();
            $target.show();
            $target.find('input:eq(0)').focus();
        }
    });

    allNextBtn.click(function() {
        var curStep = $(this).closest(".setup-content"),
            curStepBtn = curStep.attr("id"),
            nextStepWizard = $('div.setup-panel div a[href="#' + curStepBtn + '"]').parent().next().children("a"),
            curInputs = curStep.find("input[type='text'],input[type='url']"),
            isValid = true;

        $(".form-group").removeClass("has-error");
        for (var i = 0; i < curInputs.length; i++) {
            if (!curInputs[i].validity.valid) {
                isValid = false;
                $(curInputs[i]).closest(".form-group").addClass("has-error");
            }
        }

        if (isValid)
            nextStepWizard.removeAttr('disabled').trigger('click');
    });

    $('div.setup-panel div a.btn-primary').trigger('click');
});
```

```css
body {
    margin-top: 40px;
}

.stepwizard-step p {
    margin-top: 10px;
}

.stepwizard-row {
    display: table-row;
}

.stepwizard {
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
}

.stepwizard-step button[disabled] {
    opacity: 1 !important;
    filter: alpha(opacity=100) !important;
}

.stepwizard-row:before {
    top: 14px;
    bottom: 0;
    position: absolute;
    content: " ";
    width: 100%;
    height: 1px;
    background-color: #ccc;
    z-order: 0;
}

.stepwizard-step {
    display: table-cell;
    text-align: center;
    position: relative;
}

.btn-circle {
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 6px 0;
    font-size: 12px;
    line-height: 1.428571429;
    border-radius: 15px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html lang="en">

<head>

  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
  <meta name="description" content="">
  <meta name="author" content="">

  <title>Vaimenu.it | Registra il tuo locale</title>

  <!-- Custom fonts for this theme -->
  <link href="vendor/fontawesome-free/css/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat:400,700" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:400,700,400italic,700italic" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

  <!-- Theme CSS -->
  <link href="css/freelancer.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="css/speeder.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>

 


  <!-- Navigation -->
  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg bg-secondary text-uppercase fixed-top" id="mainNav">
    <div class="container">
      <a class="navbar-brand js-scroll-trigger logo" href="#page-top"  ><p class="text-lowercase"><img src="img/vaimenu.png" width="40" height="40" alt=""/>  www.vaimenu.it</p></a>
<button class="navbar-toggler navbar-toggler-right text-uppercase font-weight-bold bg-primary text-white rounded" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarResponsive" aria-controls="navbarResponsive" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
     
      <i class="fas fa-bars"></i>
    </button>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarResponsive">
        <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
          <li class="nav-item mx-0 mx-lg-1">
            <a class="nav-link py-3 px-0 px-lg-3 rounded js-scroll-trigger" href="#portfolio">Portfolio</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item mx-0 mx-lg-1">
            <a class="nav-link py-3 px-0 px-lg-3 rounded js-scroll-trigger" href="#about">About</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item mx-0 mx-lg-1">
            <a class="nav-link py-3 px-0 px-lg-3 rounded js-scroll-trigger" href="#contact">Contact</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>
 
  <!-- Masthead -->
 <body id="page-top">
<header class="primasection">
   <div class="container-fluid col-md-4 offset-md-1 supe" style="float: left; -webkit-box-shadow: 4px 5px 15px #000000; box-shadow: 4px 5px 15px #000000;">  
    <h1 class="text-danger ">Fai diventare il tuo locale un punto di riferimento!</h1>  
    <h3>Hai un locale e vorresti fare più eventi?</h3>  
     <h3 >I clienti, che cercheranno nelle vicinanze un menu ideale per il proprio evento, troveranno il <strong><em>tuo locale!</em></strong> E se non hai tempo, inseriremo noi i tuoi menu grauitamente!</h3>
   <h4 class="text-danger">*Nessuna commissione e nessun costo nascosto!</h4>
   </div>
 </head>
 
 
 <div class="container-fluid col-xl-3 col-lg-6 col-md-7 offset-lg-1 " style="float: left; margin-top: 72px;">
<div class="container form">
    <div class="stepwizard">
        <div class="stepwizard-row setup-panel">
            <div class="stepwizard-step">
                <a href="#step-1" type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-circle">1</a>
                <p>Locale</p>
            </div>
            <div class="stepwizard-step">
                <a href="#step-2" type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-circle" disabled="disabled">2</a>
                <p>Indirizzo</p>
            </div>
            <div class="stepwizard-step">
                <a href="#step-3" type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-circle" disabled="disabled">3</a>
                <p>Immagini</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <form role="form" id="myform" action='/save'>
        <div class="row setup-content" id="step-1">
            <div class="col-12">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <h3> Inserisci il tuo locale</h3>
      <div class="mb-3">
       
                    <div class="form-group was-validated">  
                     <label  class="control-label ">Nome del locale</label>
                       <input minlength="4" type="text" class="form-control" name="name" placeholder="nome del tuo locale" required/>
      <div class="valid-feedback">
      Bel nome!
    </div>
  </div>
                    </div>
       
                    <div class="form-group was-validated">
                        <label class="control-label">Email del tuo locale</label>
                      <input  type="email" class="form-control" placeholder="tuoristorante@mail.com" required />
      <div class="valid-feedback">
      Perfetto!
    </div>
                    </div>
          <div class="form-group was-validated" >  
                     <label  class="control-label">Numero di telefono del locale</label>
                       <input type="number"  class="form-control" name="fatt_txt_reg_telefono" placeholder="numero del tuo locale" required />
     <div class="valid-feedback">
      I clienti ti troveranno a questo numero !
    </div>
     </div>
             <button class="btn btn-warning nextBtn btn-lg fa-pull-right" type="confirm">Avanti<img src="img/arrow-right.svg"></button>
  
</div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row setup-content" id="step-2">
            <div class="col-12">
                <div class="col-12">
                    <h3> Indirizzo</h3>
     <div class="row">
                    <div class="form-group was-validated col-8">    
       <label class="control-label  ">Indirizzo</label> 
                      <input type="text"  class="form-control" name="indirizzo" placeholder="Indirizzo" required  />
     </div>
     <div class="form-group was-validated col-4"> 
      <label class="control-label ">N.</label>
       <input type="text"  class="form-control " name="civico" placeholder="numero" required  /> 
       
                    </div>
      </div>
                    <div class="form-group was-validated ">
                        <label class="control-label">Città</label>
                      <input maxlength="200" type="City" class="form-control" name="citta" placeholder="Città" required />
                    </div>
     <div class="form-group was-validated ">
                        <label class="control-label">Provincia</label>
                      <select id="provincia" name="provincia" maxlength="200" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Provincia" required />
      
                    </div>
     <div class="form-group was-validated">
                        <label class="control-label">CAP</label>
                      <input maxlength="200" type="CAP" class="form-control" name="fatt_txt_reg_cap" placeholder="CAP" required />
                    </div>
                    <button class="btn btn-warning nextBtn btn-lg fa-pull-right" type="confirm">Avanti<img src="img/arrow-right.svg"></button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row setup-content" id="step-3">
            <div class="col-12">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <h3> Inviaci i tuoi menu! </h3>
                    <h6>Scatta una foto a 2 menu che proponi per gli eventi nel tuo locale, Ti creeremo un pannello di controllo personalizzato e Penseremo a tutto noi!</h6>
     <hr>
                    <div class="form-group was-validated ">
                       <label class="control-label">Menu1</label>
                    <input type="file"  required>
  
</div>
      <div class="form-group was-validated ">
                       <label class="control-label">Menu2</label>
                    <input type="file"  required>
   
     <hr>
     <div class="form-group was-validated  ">
      <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox mb-3" >
   <input  type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="customControlValidation1"  required>
    <label class="custom-control-label" for="customControlValidation1" ><small>Dichiaro di aver letto, accettato e di concordare con le <a href="https://www.google.it/" target="_blank" >Clausole Generali e l'Informativa sulla privacy.</a> Vaimenu.it permette ai locali e agli ospiti di comunicare tramite Vaimenu.it, che riceve ed elabora le comunicazioni in conformità con l'Informativa sulla privacy e le Clausole Generali di Vaimenu.it.</small></label>
    
       </div>
   
      <div class="form-group was-validated  ">
      <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox mb-3" >
   <input  type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="customControlValidation2"  checked>
    <label class="custom-control-label" for="customControlValidation2" ><small>Voglio iscrivermi alla newsletter per ricevere promozioni ed altre comunicazione da parte di vaimenu.it</small></label>
    
      </div>
         
                    <button class="btn btn-success btn-lg fa-pull-right" type="submit">Finito!<img src="img/star.svg" style="top: auto"></button>
                </div>
            </div>
 
 </form>
 
</div>
  </div>
  </section>
   </section>
</header>
```

Comment: You you have a fragment at the end of the URL, eg. `yourdomain.com/page#myform`?

Comment: Yes, it is created automatically even if I don't insert it. and it's #portfolio

Comment: There's your problem. If you include a fragment in the URL and it matches the `id` of an element then when the page loads it will scroll to that element. You need to remove the fragment.

Comment: I eliminated the id #, but the problem persists, when I open the page it automatically starts filling in the contact form. and then the page is moved to the form.
I try to explain myself better, when I load the page, it goes directly to the first question of the contact form.
| name (the | flashes as if you have to enter the name) sorry for my english

Comment: Possibly because you call `focus()` on the field which sets the caret to that input and scrolls it in to view

Comment: Perfect!!!!!! thank you very much! i replaced with notfocus and it worked

Comment: Excellent, I added it as an answer for you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given your code there's two reasons this could be happening. The first is that you're including a fragment in the URL, eg. `yourdomain.com/page#myform`. If the fragment matches the id of an element in the DOM then when the page loads it will scroll to that element. To stop this, remove the fragment or change the `id` of the element.

Also you're calling `focus()` on an `input` element. This sets the caret in to the field and also scrolls it in to view. If you don't want this to occur, remove the call to `focus()`.